# Change in data made by $http inside a factory is not reflected to the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory, angularjs-digest

I'm trying to create a dynamic form based on an object.
For example: I'd like that generated select boxes will contain options if given, otherwise a factory will fetch them using ajax, something like this:

Markup:

```
<select ng-repeat="select in selects"
        ng-init="options = refactor.options(select)"
        ng-options="option in options">
</select>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, refactor) {
   $scope.refactor = refactor;
   $scope.selects = [
          { text: "Country", value="chosen.country", options=["France", "England"] },
          { text: "Gender", value="chosen.gender", options="/gender" }
        ]
});
```

Factory:

```
myApp.factory('refactor', function($scope, $http) {
  return {
    options: function(select) {
      if(typeof(select.options) === 'object') { return select.options };
      // otherwise assume select.options is 
      // a path to fetch options by ajax:
      $http.get(select.options).success(function(data) {
         select.options = data; // data == ['male', 'female']
      });

      return []; // placeholder until promise is fulfilled
    }
  }
})
```

The data ( $scope.selects ) gets updated as expected, yet the DOM is not, which probably means refactor.options() is not being invoked again in response to the change. I tried to force an update by passing the scope object to the factory and invoke $apply on it, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: try this if it works `ng-options="option in select.options"`

Comment: At the first iteration, one of the options vars is a string (a path, '/gender'), which is not iterable, and will probably raise an exception.

Comment: @Abdul23, your general direction was true after all: the variable I was initializing in ng-init did not take any effect after updating select.options, so iterating select.options instead eventually solved the problem. I suggest you post that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-init="data = refactor.options(select)"` so after getting data from `ajax` data would be filled up with `options` then you could use `ng-options` as instead of `ng-options="option in data.options"`.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-repeat="select in selects"
    ng-init="data = refactor.options(select)"
    ng-options="option in data.options">
</select>
```

Comment: there is no "data" property in options (?)

Comment: @Kludge that's my bad..misplaced the `options` in answer..try the updated answer..

Comment: It seems like you just changed the name of the options containing variable from 'options' to 'data'... I appreciate the fact you're trying to help but the issue is that the DOM is not being updated although the data is.

Comment: for make it working you should be return `select.options` then you could use data option on html

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
myApp.factory('refactor', function($scope, $http) {

return {
    options: function(select) {
               var menuItems={
                     options:[]
                  }

                if(typeof(select.options) === 'object'){
                   menuItems.options=select.options
                };

               // otherwise assume select.options is 
               // a path to fetch options by ajax:

               $http.get(select.options).success(function(data) {
                    select.options = data; 
                    menuItems.options=data;// data == ['male', 'female']
               });

               return menuItems; // placeholder until promise is fulfilled
            }
       }
});
```

Then inside your view it should go like this

```
<select ng-repeat="select in selects"
    ng-init="menuItems= refactor.options(select)"
    ng-options="option in menuItems.options">
</select>
```